# Using pipes to pass data between child processes in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

My homework task is to write a C program that creates 4 child processes and each child has to do something with an integer number and send it to the next child that does something else with it and the last one has to print the changed value. I have to use anonymous pipes to communicate between children. Parent process has no other work than to open pipes for children. I have written the program, but the problem is I get funny output when I try to print the number using the last child. It prints out 8 numbers instead of one (actually one of them is the right one). The part of code is following:

```
int pipe1[2];
int pipe2[2];
int pipe3[2];
pipe(pipe1);
pipe(pipe2);
pipe(pipe3);

int j;

close(pipe1[1]);   //close pipes for writing on parent process
close(pipe2[1]);
close(pipe3[1]);

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   switch(fork()) {
   case 0:
       if (j == 0) {
          int value = 100;
          write(pipe1[1], &value, sizeof(int));
          close(pipe1[1]);
       }
       else if (j == 1) {
          int value;
          read(pipe1[0], &value, sizeof(int));
          close(pipe1[0]);
          value = value * 10;
          write(pipe2[1], &value, sizeof(int));
          close(pipe2[1]);
       }
    //and so on until the last process
       else if (j == 3) {
          int value;
          read(pipe3[0], &value, sizeof(int));
          char buf[4] = {0};
          memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
          snprintf(buf, sizeof(value), "%d ", value);
          write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
       }
       break;
   }
}
close(pipe1[0]);
close(pipe2[0]);
close(pipe3[0]);
sleep(1);

int k;

for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
   wait(0);
}
```

What do I have to do for this case, just to get one (and the proper one) output?

Comment: You need buf[5] i think, assuming int is 4 byte long in your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think happens when one of your child processes executes the `break` statement in the code you presented?  Hint: it doesn't exit.

Additionally, I'm doubtful that your pipes can work quite like that.  You close the write ends of two of them (one of those twice) *before* forking any children.  Those will not magically be reopened for the children, so their whole pipes are useless.

Comment: sorry I edited the code... I ment close(pipe3[1]).. So I shouldn't close pipes before switch case and in every if statement I need _exit(0) at the end?

Comment: @Luki, The parent should not close its copy of any pipe end before forking all children that need to use that pipe end.  Avoiding all closures until after the loop would be a simple way to accomplish that.  You do need to ensure that each child exits when it has completed its intended work; putting an `_exit(0)` in each one's `if` block would be one way to accomplish that.

Comment: I have solved it :) Thank you for a very clear answer.

Comment: I don't understand how your code works even after all comments ans answers you received, you never write in pipe3 (the if case j == 2 is missing)